# Continuity from property of constriction images of spheres

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, continuity

Let $D\subset\mathbb R^n$ --- domain and mapping $\varphi:D\to \mathbb R^n$.

The following property holds

> There is a set $T\subset D$ s. t. measure $|D\setminus T|=0$ and for every point 
>   $x\in T$ 
>   $$
> \sup\limits_{y\in \varphi(S(x,r))}\|y-\varphi(x)\| \to 0
> $$
>   when $r\to0$ and $r\not\in\Sigma_x$ for some set $\Sigma_x$ of 1-measure zero. S(x,r) are sphere centered at x with radius r.

- As jflipp shown below  there is no way to prove that mapping $\varphi$ is continuous on $D$.
- However I think that it would be possible to redefine mapping $\varphi$ on $D\setminus T$ s. t. new mapping $\varphi:D\to\mathbb R^n$ be continuous on $D$. Could this be a true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $S(x,r)$ is the sphere centered at $x$ with radius $r$. I think that $\phi$ is not necessarily continuous. A counterexample is the following.
We set $n := 1$, $D := (-1,1)$ and define $\phi:D\rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $\phi(x) = 0$ if $x\neq 0$ and $\phi(0) = 1$. Note that $\phi$ is not continuous. Then, we put $T := D \setminus \{0\}$. With that, we have measure(D\T) = $0$. Moreover, for every $x \in T$ and $r < |x|$ ,we have $\phi(S(x,r)) = \{0\}$ and $\phi(x) = 0$, so $\sup_{y \in \phi(S(x,r))}\|y - \phi(x)\| \rightarrow 0$ for $r \rightarrow 0$ and fixed $x$.
Thus, our $\phi$ satisfies all your conditions, but is not continuous.

Comment: You are right. Maybe it is possible to find continuous representation for such mappinngs. In your example $\phi$ has the continuous representation.

Comment: I think it's not always true that we have a continuous continuation of $\phi$ from $T$ to all of $D$. For example, take $D$ and $T$ as in my answer and define $\psi:D\rightarrow\mathbb R$ by $\psi(x) = -1$ for $x <0$, $\psi(0) = 0$, and $\psi(x) = 1$ for $x > 0$. Then $\sup_{y \in \psi(S(x,r))}\|y - \psi(x)\| \rightarrow 0$ for $r\rightarrow 0$ and fixed $x \in T$ since $\psi$ is locally constant on $T$ (same argument as in my answer). But $\psi|_T$ doesn't have a continuous continuation to all of $D$.

Comment: Agree, my hypothesis fails)